# loopj onProgress missing

Tags: progress-bar, loopj

Using loopJ for the first time. Pretty nice. However, I see posts describing the @Override onProgress().  However, it does not seem to be available any longer?

I see the V/AsynchHttoPH Progress xx% in the debugger so the data is there someplace. How can I can at this to update my horizontal Progress bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it seems nobody is using loopj library.
I'm switching to Retrofit 2.  Hopefully it will do what I need.
Thanks.